# I am getting Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined" for code below

Tags: javascript

THe below is a code for a simple snake game. The node array statement works well outside the function but give error in side...

```
//store all nodes in a array

const nodeArray=document.getElementsByClassName("node")

//create a snake

let snake=[12,13,14,15,16]

snakeMake()

function snakeMake(){
    for (let x=0;x<=snake.length;x++){
        nodeArray[snake[x]].style.backgroundColor=("white")  
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you have some elements with `node` class at index of `12,13,14,15,16`? in other words are you sure you have 16 elements with `node` class?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the class `node` has enough elements to match `snake`.
For example, we have 13 tags with class `node`, about the loop you can't complete the for loop, so if you want to execute this function you must make sure the number of tags uses class `node`. meets or is equal to or higher than the highest-valued element in `snake`

Answer (score 0):

It may be just [off-by-one error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error):

`x <= snake.length` should be `x < snake.length` as `snake[x]` with `x === snake.length` is  `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

Your error means that `nodeArray[snake[x]]` evaluates to `undefined`.  Upon which you then call `undefined.style`.

The first reason is probably `x <= snake.length` in your for-loop. Upon the last iteration `x` will be set to `snake.length` (`5`), since your `snake` array only has 5 elements with indexes `0-4` this will result in `undefined`

```
let snake=[12,13,14,15,16]
//          0  1  2  3  4

snake[5] //=> undefined
```

This value is then used to access your `nodeArray`.

```
nodeArray[undefined] //=> undefined
```

Upon which `.style` is called that causes the error.

```
undefined.style //=> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined" for code below
// or in full
nodeArray[snake[5]].style //=> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined" for code below
```

This issue can be solved by changing `<=` into `<` within `x <= snake.length`. Which makes sure the maximum `x` used is `4` and not `5`.

If the above doesn't solve your problem your `nodeArray` is probably missing one of the indexes `[12,13,14,15,16]` (aka you have to few elements with `class="node"`, make sure you have at least 17). When you use an index that is out of bounds `undefined` is returned.